# Во время загрузки...

Tags: локализация, linux

Во время загрузки/выкл/перезагрузке в CentOS 6 русский текст отображается крякозябрами.
Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 3):

Не уверен, но думаю стоит смотреть в сторону локали. Cперва проверим командой "locale", какая локаль установлена. Вывод покажет примерно следующее:

```
LANG=ru_UA.UTF-8LANGUAGE=LC_CTYPE="ru_UA.UTF-8"LC_NUMERIC="ru_UA.UTF-8"LC_TIME="ru_UA.UTF-8"LC_COLLATE="ru_UA.UTF-8"LC_MONETARY="ru_UA.UTF-8"LC_MESSAGES="ru_UA.UTF-8"LC_PAPER="ru_UA.UTF-8"LC_NAME="ru_UA.UTF-8"LC_ADDRESS="ru_UA.UTF-8"LC_TELEPHONE="ru_UA.UTF-8"LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_UA.UTF-8"LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_UA.UTF-8"LC_ALL=
```

Для того чтобы проверить наличие готовых локалей в системе выполняем команду

```
locale -a | grep ru
```

И в выводе команды ищем необходимую нам локаль. Для случая с кодировкой UTF-8 необходимая локаль имеет вид ru_RU.utf8. Если такая строка есть в выводе команды то делаем следующее:

Создаем файл /etc/sysconfig/i18n командой:

```
touch /etc/sysconfig/i18n
```

После чего в файл пишем следующие строки:

```
LANG="ru_RU.UTF-8"SUPPORTED="ru_RU.UTF-8:ru_RU:ru"SYSFONT="latarcyrheb-sun16"
```

После этих изменений сохраняем файл, выходим из консоли и заходим в нее опять. После этих действий мы наблюдаем русский шрифт в локали.Если же при выводе команды

```
locale -a | grep ru
```

нет русской локали то ее необходимо сделать. Команда для этого выглядит так:

```
localedef  -i ru_RU -f UTF-8 ru_RU.UTF-8
```

Comment: в debian настраиваю следующим образом:sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales.Выбираю нужные,сохроняюсь,перезагружаюсь.